# php header location not working in script

Tags: php, javascript, forms, html

Whenever I submit my form, I encounter this error through turning on error reporting in php:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cranium/includes/header.inc.php:14) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cranium/includes/register.inc.php on line 65

In my header.inc.php, I have this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Cranium eSolutions</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cranium/css/style.css">
  <script src="/cranium/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

I use include_once to include this code in my pages. (line 14 points to the body tag and there are no whitespaces or whatsoever after that).

In my register.inc.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtUser']));

//generate password
$password = generatePassword(10,5);


$email = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtEmail']));

//random code
$com_code = sha1(uniqid(rand()));


$fName = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtFname']));
$lName = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtLname']));
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtAddress']));
$city = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtCity']));
$zip = (int)$_POST['txtZip'];
$country = $_POST['txtCountry'];
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtMobileNo']));
$office = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtOfficeNo']));
$specialty = $_POST['txtFOS'];
$prof = $_POST['txtProf'];



//checkbox
$practiceFetch = $_POST['chkSOP'];
$n = count($practiceFetch);
$practice = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    $practice .= $practiceFetch[$i].', ';
}
$practice = substr($practice,0,-2);



$coordinator = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtPrimaryCoord']));
$relationship = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtRelationship']));
$relEmail = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtRelEmail']));
$feedback = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtHow']));

//service concat
//if ($_POST['txtSubService']) $subService = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes(' - '.$_POST['txtSubService']));
//$service = mysql_real_escape_string(stripcslashes($_POST['txtService'])).$subService;
$service = 'tae';


//start Query
require_once('../includes/db.config.php');
$checkQuery = "SELECT username FROM tblAccounts WHERE username='$username'";
$checkResult = mysqli_query($cxn,$checkQuery);
if (mysqli_num_rows($checkResult) <= 0) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO tblAccounts VALUES('','$username','$password','$fName','$lName','$address','$email','$com_code','$city',$zip,'$country',$mobile,$office,'$specialty','$prof','$practice','$coordinator','$relationship','$relEmail','$feedback','$service')";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query);
    //email confirmation
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Confirmation from Cranium eSolutions Inc., to $username";
    $header = "Cranium eSolutions Inc.: Confirmation from craniumesolutions.com";
    $message = "Please click the link below to verify and activate your account. <br />";
    $message .= "http://imageworkz.asia/Cranium-Trial/confirm.php?passkey=$com_code";
    $sentmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    if($sentmail) {
        header('Location: http://www.google.com');
    } else {
        header('Location: http://localhost/cranium/verificationfail.html');
    }
} else {

    echo '<span style="color:red;">Username already exists</span>';

}
?>
```

line 65 points to header('Location: www.google.com.');

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Did you even try to google for the error message? Because this is such a common mistake...

Comment: you have `echo` in your `header.inc.php`

Comment: header() fails to work if there is already some output echoed. check the lines and function calls before header('location: www.google.com')

Comment: It's probably an error message that's being displayed (you're setting this to `On` above). Check your logs for errors.

Comment: Have a read to clear your confusion: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php :)

Comment: @MartinsBriedis I did google that's why I wrote that whitespaces can be the issue. I wrote the whole content of header.inc.php and it pointed to a no white-spaced body tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 8):

**You cannot output anything before `header()` call.** Check your code if something is being echoed, or there are any errors displayed.

Look at `header.inc.php` line 14. That's where something is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by using an output buffer.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php

This will buffer the output until you flush it or your script is finished.
No output before => no problem!

Answer (score 0):

header.ing.php IS output.

The split second you run "include('header.inc.php') you have output.

Solution: run it later.

---

Also, add "exit" after your header(location) commands to stop the rest of the script being executed. PHP will continue to run.